# Removing the Duplicates in the drop down

Tags: jquery

I got values from a csv file and those values I have placed in respective dropdowns. The issues is that in csv file I have duplicate entries so the same duplicate entries are in the drop down. I need to remove the duplicates. code for placing in to drop down i am not using select option code  i am using `"$("#checkboxes").append("<input type='checkbox' class ='chk'   name='locationthemes' onclick='pandu();' value ="+cells[0]+"> " +cells[0] + " </input><br>");"`

code for getting the values from csv file:

```
var list=[];
var region =[];
var state=[];
var state1=[];
var accname=[];
$(document).ready(function() {
 // AJAX in the data file
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "data.csv",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {processData(data);}
        });

    // Let's process the data from the data file
    function processData(data) {
        var table = $("<table />");
                   var rows = data.split(/\r\n|\n/);
                    for (var i = 1; i < rows.length-1; i++) {


                        var row = $("<tr />");
                        cells = rows[i].split(/,(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))/);
                        list.push(cells)
                        var newvalue=cells[1].replace("\"", ""); 
                        var pandu=cells[0];

                       // var panduuu=jQuery.unique(cells[0]);
                        //alert("panduuu::"+panduuu)

                            $("#checkboxes").append("<input type='checkbox' class ='chk'   name='locationthemes' onclick='pandu();' value ="+cells[0]+"> " +cells[0] + " </input><br>");                        



                         table.append(row);

                    }


    }


});
```

Comment: I tried to make it more readable but I did not understand your last sentence. As for duplicates, why not test list.indexOf(cells)!=-1

Comment: That is not a useful comment. Errors in the console? Console.log list and cells?

Comment: In console no errors @mplungjan

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
var rows = data.split(/\r\n|\n/);
```

To this:

```
var rows = $.unique(data.split(/\r\n|\n/));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var rows = data.split(/\r\n|\n/);
console.log(rows.length);

var data = unique(rows);
console.log(data.length);
for (var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++) {
      //Populate your drop down here
}

function unique(array) {
   return $.grep(array, function (elem, index) {
        return index === $.inArray(elem, array);
   });
}
```

Comment: duplicates are not removes and in console i didt not get any errors@Nasir

Comment: Sample data I have used in csv was 
Test
Data
Test
I have added logs for data length before and after filtering unique records